# Using Cell Reference in Query formula - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have the following Query formula populating for items next to "Fruits".

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!$A$2:$C,"SELECT B, C WHERE A = 'Fruits' ",1)
```

I'd like to substitute the "Fruits" text value with a reference to a specific cell, like A2.

That way if I change the value in A2 from "Fruits" to "Fruit", I don't need to update the QUERY Formula

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-16hiUGu9Ced2gJ_1r8KDzDspUxf3ldhFGrXElLjA0/edit?usp=sharing) to a sample sheet.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use below formula-

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!$A$2:$C,"SELECT B, C WHERE A = '" & A2 & "'",1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by playing around a bit. This is what worked:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!$A$2:$C,"SELECT B, C WHERE A = '"&A2&"' ",1)
```